# Display webpage inside another webpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display webpage inside another webpage
Suppose I want to display xyz.com/child.aspx page inside abc.com/parent.aspx page.

I can use iframe but I have http credential applied on xyz.com. I searched on net but still confused what should I use?

I use asp.net 4.5 c#.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you authenticate in the parent page you will have no problems accessing a child page as long as all pages are in the same domain.

Comment: It is in different domain.

Comment: Then the user will have to authenticate in the child page too or you can pass some kind of authentication token to the child app from the parent one.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error in the iframe?

Comment: @tucaz At the time of calling xyz.com/child.aspx, I have to pass HTTP credential. But I dont know exactly how I use it? I tried HttpClient class but it does not give me CSS.  So finding other options.

Comment: this abc.com/parent.aspx page - can this be made a MasterPage instead. I am not sure about your design constraints tho. But i believe iframe is the quickest way to achieve what you want to.

Comment: I tried <iframe src="http://username:password@wiki.xxx.com/Application_Feature"></iframe> but not working

Answer (score 0):

if the 2 sites are hosted from the same network (low latency between them) you could use state server for session management. that way, when you authenticate on one site, you will also be authenticated on the other, and share user state across them.

its pretty simple, in your web config of each web server you'd point to the state server (which could be located on one of the web servers)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
       stateConnectionString="192.168.1.103:42424"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_State_Management%E2%80%94Storing_Session_State_out_of_Process

Comment: Both are hosted on different servers.